# Power series representation of $ f(x) = \frac{(x+2)^2}{x^2+1} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I'm trying to find the power series representation of $ f(x) = \frac{(x+2)^2}{x^2+1} $

Here is what I tried:

$$
f(x) = \frac{((x+2)^2}{x^2+1}=(x+2)^2\frac{1}{1-(-x^2)}
$$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-x^2)^{n-1}=1-x^2+x^4-x^6+x^8-+...
$$
$$
f(x)=(x+2)^2[1-x^2+x^4-x^6+x^8-+...] =(x+2) -(x+2)x^2+(x+2)x^4-(x+2)x^6+(x+2)x^8-+...
$$

I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: Where did your square on the $(x+2)^2$ go in your final step?

Comment: Power series representation about what -- about $x_0=0$ or about $x_0=-2$? In other words, are you looking for a representation in powers of $x$ or in powers of $x+2$? Until you specify the question, it's too ambiguous and can't be answered.

Comment: Better to multiply ou $x^2 + 4x + 4$ then multiply by your series for $\frac{1}{1 + x^2}$

There will be some simplifications possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to write 
$$f(x) = \frac{(x+2)^2}{x^2+1}=\frac{x^2+4x+4}{x^2+1}=1+\frac{4x+3}{x^2+1}=1+(4x+3) (1-x^2+x^4-x^6+x^8+\cdots)=4+4x-3x^2-4x^3+\cdots$$